# Creating this array programmatically?

Tags: ruby, arrays, refactoring

I'm currently populating a simple array like so:

```
queues = %w(rate_limit_000 rate_limit_001 rate_limit_002 rate_limit_003 rate_limit_004 rate_limit_005 rate_limit_006 rate_limit_007 rate_limit_008 rate_limit_009 rate_limit_010 rate_limit_011 rate_limit_012)
```

That's ripe for refactoring. So what's the easiest way to build that array without manually adding items?

The only difference between the item names are those last 3 digits, which should always be 3 digits, but I do need to set a limit on how high it goes.

Comment: Questions about refactoring or the best way to write something, should be asked on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-25)?

```
(0..12).map { |i| "rate_limit_%03d" % i }
# => ["rate_limit_000", "rate_limit_001", "rate_limit_002", ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this, using [`String#rjust`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-rjust) method:

```
(0..12).map do |i|
  "rate_limit_#{i.to_s.rjust(3, '0')}"
end
```